# exec-path-from-shell message when starting emacs

Tags: bash, shell, emacs

I have exec-path-from-shell in my init.el like thisL

```
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

Whenever I start emacs, I get the following message:

> You appear to be setting environment variables ("PATH" "MANPATH") in
>   your .bashrc or .zshrc: those files are only read by interactive
>   shells, so you should instead set environment variables in startup
>   files like .profile, .bash_profile or .zshenv.  Refer to your shell's
>   man page for more info.  Customize `exec-path-from-shell-arguments' to
>   remove "-i" when done, or disable
>   `exec-path-from-shell-check-startup-files' to disable this message.
>   For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.

Comment: emacs.stackexchange.com may be a better place for this question.

Comment: The warning message is very clear about what you should do to get rid of the warning. What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the explanation or what the problem is that it is warning against.

Comment: Environment variables that should affect all shells, not just interactive shells, should be set in `.profile`, not `.bashrc`, because `.bashrc`. So you should move the assignment of those variables to the correct startup file. Or if you don't want Emacs to warn you about this, because you're happy the way it is, disable the `exec-path-from-shell-check-startup-files` option using `M-x customize`.

Comment: MIne is in my .zshenv file which according to the message is correct.  https://github.com/dagda1/dots/blob/master/.zshenv.  I am linking to files that contain the vars but it seems correct to me

Comment: Maybe you set it in both, and it doesn't check for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want Emacs to warn about the location of your environment variable settings, disable that option with:

```
(setq exec-path-from-shell-check-startup-files nil)
```

Put that before

```
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

in your `.emacs`.